# How to get response from browser when a file is downloaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, download

I want to get a response when the download starts, I'm submitting a form which is an HTML form post and I get a file as return which already Flush in the controller. so there is no response from the server-side. Is there any way to get a response from the browser side to know the download is started or not?

```
function GenerateReport() {
    debugger;
    ChangeButtonPatchView("Report", "buttonPatch", "DisabledGenerateRpt");
    $('#Action').val('Report');
    $('#btnPrintOrSaveReport').trigger('click');
    setInterval(function () {
        ChangeButtonPatchView("Report", "buttonPatch", "SCurvePercentageComplete");      
    },2000);  
}
```

in this code, the submit button is triggered. I want to check the browser response in this function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to monitor the download status from Javascript alone if you are triggering a regular download. An extension can use the downloads API ([Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads)/[FF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads)) to query the progress of a download and a page can do the same using a [XMLHttpRequest and the onProgress event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onprogress), but currently no major browser has a way to query the progress of a download with Javascript alone.

If you can offload the downloading to a server-side script you could however [track the download using a unique token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download).

Comment: ohh thats the problem i have already checked may references. I just need a response that the download is started.

Comment: @DhanilDinesan No browser that I know of will emit an event that the download has started, sadly. The easiest solution would be to use a server-side download host that can track individual downloads and send the status back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

here is my try and it's working fine. 
in Controller, I have added a cookie

```
HttpCookie dwnloadResponse = new HttpCookie("dwnloadResponse");
                dwnloadResponse["Complete"] = "true";
                Response.Cookies.Add(dwnloadResponse);
```

and using this cookie name I do my checking in javascript.

```
 function GenerateReport() {
    debugger;
    ChangeButtonPatchView("Report", "buttonPatch", "DisabledGenerateRpt");
    $('#Action').val('Report');
    $('#btnPrintOrSaveReport').trigger('click');
    _responseCheckTimer = setInterval(function () {
        debugger;
        if (document.cookie.indexOf('dwnloadResponse') !== -1) {
            ChangeButtonPatchView("Report", "buttonPatch", "SCurvePercentageComplete");
            var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + 0);
            var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = "dwnloadResponse=" + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
            clearTimeout(_responseCheckTimer);
        }      
    },1000);          
}
```

this will check the cookie is available in the browser. if the cookie is not present it will return a -1 value. Then we will remove the cookie and stops the timer.